# This white wire is hot right?

Tags: electrical

I have an outlet that is controlled by a light switch. I hate these and wanted to make the outlet always hot to avoid turning it off by accident when turning off the light switch

However, when I pulled out the light switch it looked weird to me. I have a single black, single white, and ground wire going to the switch only.

I suspect that whoever installed the outlet used a white wire as hot but didn't label it, but I wanted to ask if anyone else thought this was weird or if this is done special way to wire an outlet I couldn't find online.

The first image is the light switch. The second is the outlet. The wire I'm touching is actually black, but it looks white at the end because of some historical painting by my guess.

[image: Switch]
[image: outlet]

Comment: Don't assume, test for the hot(s) with a multimeter. Then you can be SURE what is there.

Comment: It won't matter, remove the switch and wire nut the 2 wires together, that will make the box hot full time. If you want to remove the box it will require more info, and I would not suggest it, most switched receptacles are required by code, and if you sold your home, a home inspector might pick up on it.

Comment: Are there some white wires in the outlet box?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking squarely into the back of the outlet box please?

Comment: @gairfowl although that answer is similar and correct with electrical code changes every 3 years and that reference left out the requirement for a switched receptacle is a requirement when there is not a permanent fixture with a switch.  And since that answer there has been additional code changes that were not discussed as this was a single throw switch. Be cautious linking old answers as sometimes they are wrong by today’s code. Specifically if asked on a modern building that is no longer code compliant as of the last code cycle for a single throw switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a white that is hot at a switch is called a switch leg and code required the white wire to be always hot so it would not be mistaken for a neutral if it was on the switched side this has been code for decades.

Put a wire nut on the black to white and there will be no more switch interference with the receptacle.

Note if there is not a light in the room it is a requirement to have a switched receptacle so taking out the switch may violate code.

Comment: Yes, this is an important point. To clarify to the OP: there must be a ceiling outlet (box) for a light operated by a switch near the door, or that switch must control a receptacle (like in your question). Just having a light is -I believe- not enough. It must be switched at the door. It's not a fire hazard, but if a visitor trips & injures in the dark, and there was no light switch there, it could have consequences.